# Boost in sunspot (solr)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, solr, sunspot

In sunspot you can hint relevancy using the :boost option:

```
text :name, :boost => 2.0
```

From this link, I think that the default boost is 1:
http://lucene.apache.org/java/2_4_0/queryparsersyntax.html

My question is whether the sunspot boost amount is passed directly to the lucene boost? I'm wondering if I can do `:boost => .5` to lower the relevancy of a certain result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you are exactly right. Sunspot will use those `:boost` options for query-time boosting when it assembles the `qf` parameter.

Comment: Thanks! This is also confirmed by some testing I did.